# Checkbox trouble in jQuery, AJAX and MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have some trouble sending the value from a variable set with a checkbox to my MySQL database.

Ok.

I have a checkbox, e-mail field and a button:

```
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="emailSubCheck"> Check me</label>

    <input type="text" class="form-control email-field" id="emailInput" name="email" placeholder="Your e-mail...">

    <button id="sendReportAsMail" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Send</button>
```

I then run this jQuery (it is the checked variable causing me trouble. It always returns 0 to the database. No matter what I do):

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
var checked;
function checkEmailSub() {

$('#emailSubCheck').click( function() {
  if ($('#emailSubCheck').is(':checked')) {
      checked = 1;
    } else {
      checked = 0;
    }
  });
}
checkEmailSub();

$("#sendReportAsMail").click(function(){

var email = $('#emailInput').val();

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"sendSubmits.php",
        data:"email="+email+"&checked="+checked, 
          success:function(data){
          console.log('Ok. So data have been submitted and as I get it. Checked value is now ' + checked);
        }
    });
 });
});
```

In the log it is perfectly showing 1 if I checked the box before submitting and 0 if I didn't.

This makes me believe that the jQuery (although not perfect) is working.

In my sendSubmits.php I have:

```
$email=$_POST["email"];
$checked=$POST["checked"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO sendsubmits(email, checked) VALUES ('$email', '$checked')";
```

(Notice: The DB Connection isn't included. The e-mail is perfectly inserted to the database on every submission. Just the var checked value is missing)

The `checked` column in my MySQL database is INT(1). No matter what i try it just always registers a 0.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: Try not inserting it as a string, i.e. remove the quotes around it.

Comment: What is `$('#emailSubCheck')`? It isn't shown in html.  What is value of `checked` being sent? can inspect data sent in actual request browser dev tools network or log it to console

Comment: I've tried removing quotes like this `$sql = "INSERT INTO sendsubmits(email, checked) VALUES ('$email', $checked)";`

Unfortunately didn't work. Do I have to parse it as an integer in my jQuery script also?

Sorry for ID confusion. I pasted the wrong HTML at first. It is supposed to be ID="emailSubCheck" in the checkbox.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that your SQL query is insecure, and it is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Perhaps you simply omitted the escaping and sanitization to simplify your question, but if not, please look into SQL safety techniques.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Spencer. I knew there was a problem. But I'm not quite sure how to fix it yet. It's next step. If you have a great read on it I'd love a link:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the wrong ID in your javascript, try to change the ID of your input like so :

**HTML**

```
<label><input type="checkbox" id="emailSubCheck"> Check me</label>
```

And run the checkEmailSub() function just before making your ajax request to refresh the checked variable.

**JAVSCRIPT**

```
$("#sendReportAsMail").click(function(){

var email = $('#emailInput').val();
checkEmailSub(); //Add this to refresh the checked variable.
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"sendSubmits.php",
        data:"email="+email+"&checked="+checked, 
          success:function(data){
          console.log('Ok. So data have been submitted and as I get it. Checked value is now ' + checked);
        }
    });
 });
});
```

You also forgot the `_` in your POST variable, replace this :

**PHP**

```
$checked=$POST["checked"];
```

with this :

```
$checked=$_POST["checked"];
```

Comment: Yeah!

It worked. Thanks a bunch. You saved me a headache.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you forgot the "_" symbol here:

```
$checked=$_POST["checked"];
```

And the ids "emailSubCheck" (javascript) and "emailSubscribe" (html) are different.

And also everything can be done in much easier way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sendReportAsMail").click(function(){

    var email = encodeURIComponent($('#emailInput').val());
    var checked = $("#emailSubscribe").prop("checked") ? 1 : 0;
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"sendSubmits.php",
      data:"email="+email+"&checked="+checked, 
      success:function(data){
        console.log('Ok. So data have been submitted and as I get it. Checked value is now ' + checked);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks.

Yes. Your suggestion seems way easier. I'll try and rewrite my own code in that way (I have bunch of other variables entering. Just cleaned up for the sake of posting it here). 

Thanks for optimization along the way. That's so cool!